# How can I teleport multiple players from one world/dimension to another but with same coordinates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So basically, Im making a datapack and I want to send 2+ players from a certain place in a world but when i do a certain command it will tp them to a another world but same coordinates.

Also when they're in the nether i want them to tp to the same coords but in a different nether world. And same thing with the end.

Answer (score 1):

`/execute as @a at @s in the_nether run tp @s ~ ~ ~`

This teleports everyone into the Nether, but at the coordinates they were at in the Overworld.

Comment: How would i make the datapack detect when the player is in the nether and teleport it to another nether. And same thing for the end.

Comment: What do you mean with "another Nether"? There is just one per world.

Comment: Its because im using multiverse plugin on my server. But how would i make it where i detect when the player is in the nether so it will teleport him to the next nether after a few minutes.

Comment: I have no idea how that mod works, so I can't answer that. You should have made that clear in your initial question. I recommend asking a new question, in which you link the mod, summarise how the relevant part works and state very clearly what you're trying to achieve, what you tried to make it work and what part you are currently struggling with.

Comment: It really doesn't have to do much about multiverse. All im trying to do is make it detect when im in the minecraft:nether_1. So if im in the nether it will run the command "execute as @a at @s in minecraft:nether_2 run tp @s ~ ~ ~"

Comment: Detecting being in it and teleporting to (what you said) are very different things. Detecting being in a dimension is done like this: `/execute in the_nether as @a[distance=0..] run …` And did the mod really add its new dimensions in the "`minecraft`" namespace? That's a very bad idea, you should report it as a bug, even if right now nothing bad happens, it can lead to strange problems in the future.